# object references an unsaved transient instance when I migrated to pure javaEE6

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

We have a javaEE6 application which is developed like this:
To simplify we have the following entities Interaction, Customer and Title. Customer and Title are linked like this:

```
public class Customer {
    @Embedded
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Name name = new Name();
}

@Embeddable
public class Name {
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TITLE")
    private Title title;
}

public class Title {
}
```

Then we have beans for each entities: InteractionBean, CustomersBean/CustomerBean, TitlesBean/TitleBean all are annotated with ConversationScoped.

Then in the customer page we have:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{customer.name}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{titlesBean.elements()}" var="elem" itemLabel="#{elem.label}" itemValue="#{elem}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

So we basically list the elements of the entity Title.

The beans:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class CustomerBean  {
}

@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class TitlesBean {
}
```

On the customer page, there is a next button that saves the Customer entity but that throws the above error. It seems like although both TitlesBean and CustomerBean are marked with conversationScoped, the entityManager used are different. About entityManager, it is injected in the service with the default scope like all the other services.

Before it was working but we were using annotations from seam:

```
@ExtensionManaged
@ConversationScoped
@Produces
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "pu")
@MeveoJpa
EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
I'm currently looking at PersistenceContext.EXTENDED + ConversationScoped but still not able to make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First impression

@SessionScoped and @ConversationScoped are passivation capable. Thus beans annotated by either must implement Serializable as well as the beans member properties.

Comment: Hi yes, sorry about that. Yes all the Bean and Service classes extends a base class that implements Serializable. I've nailed the problem as having different instance of entityManager, the reason why the title entity from one transaction is detached to another. But I don't have any solution yet.

Comment: Please use annotation PersistenceContext to inject the entity manager, instead of the annotation PersistenceUnit for the factory.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using PersistenceContext with JavaEE6. For now I think I'll just stick with ExtensionManaged from seam until DeltaSpike is release.